# Kong custom plugin does not work for service specific

Tags: kong, kong-plugin

I have created a kong custom plugin and trying to configure this only for specific services, it does not apply if I use it under a service, otherwise, it will work for all the services, this is my kong.yml

```
_format_version: "3.0"
_transform: true

services:
  - name: b_and_h_service2
    url: https://endpoint123aa.free.beeceptor.com
    routes:
      - name: b_and_h_route2
        paths:
          - /path2
    plugins:
      - name: kongbodyinspection
```

the plugin only works if I use plugin values as this

```
_format_version: "3.0"
_transform: true

services:
  - name: b_and_h_service2
    url: https://endpoint123aa.free.beeceptor.com
    routes:
      - name: b_and_h_route2
        paths:
          - /path2
plugins:
  - name: kongbodyinspection
```

Is there any reason the plugin does not work for specific services?

Comment: Does it work on the route level?

Comment: No, it does not work for the route level as well, inside the handler.lua I only have overridden the access method

Answer (score 0):

This is my schema.lua

```
local typedefs = require "kong.db.schema.typedefs"


return {
    name = "kongbodyinspection",
    fields = {
        {
            route = typedefs.no_route,
        },
        {
            service = typedefs.no_service,
        },
        {
            consumer = typedefs.no_consumer,
        },
        {
            protocols = typedefs.protocols_http,
        },
        {
            config = {
                type = "record",
                fields = {
                    {  token_required = { type     = "string", required = false, default  = "true" }, }
                },
            },
        },
    },
}
```

since I was using

```
        {
            service = typedefs.no_service,
        },
```

issue occurred from this part, after removing this, plugins can be used at service level as well